# How can I easily list the content of the registers before pasting?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

I use the registers a lot for copy/pasting, but I always forgot in which register my content is.

Is there a way to display the registers before pasting?

Ideally it would leave the register on screen when selecting the one we want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made up this mapping to display the register list and select the one to be pasted:

```
nnoremap "p :reg <bar> exec 'normal! "'.input('>').'p'<CR>
```

This display the register list with `:reg` and execute the normal command

```
"Xp
```

Where `X` is the result of `input()`.

Answer (score 14):

This [peekaboo](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo) plugin is pretty good for for previewing registers.  When you press `"` or `@` in normal mode, or `ctrl-r` in insert mode, a split will open to show you the register contents.

Preview from the plugin repo:

[image: peekaboo]

Comment: This plugin would be a __lot__ less obnoxious if the key bindings would be user-configurable.  Binding to `"` and `@` in normal mode breaks just about all macros that use registers.  FWIW.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not having issues with the recursive macros I tend to use, even with registers involved. The plugin disables itself when replaying macros with `@`. The README notes that non-recursive maps will cause problems. I agree that it'd be nice if it could be configured to just view the registers, though.

Comment: Here's something trivial that breaks: `:%g/text/ normal "Ayy`

Comment: The plugin has been updated to use configurable prefix.  https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo/pull/41

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using

`:reg`

It will show the contents of all registers (you can scroll through using j and k).

If you just want to show the contents of one register, you can go to command mode and type

```
: Ctrl + r
```

then the register, for example the x register

```
x
```

which will paste the contents of the register into the command line. You can then escape out of the command line after viewing your register.

Comment: What's the difference between `:dis` and `:reg`?  I always use the former.

Comment: None: `:help :dis` -> `:di[splay] [arg]        Same as :registers.  {not in Vi}`

Comment: Brilliant! This also works in Emacs' `evil-mode`, where it opens a special buffer where one can see the contents of all registers (and macros!).